# How to change the alignment of the paragraph and heading using media query

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the alignment of the paragraph and heading using media query in order to make it responsive

I tried using max-width, margin and padding but unable to get the desired result.

```css
.about-background h2 {
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding-right: 3.5em;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .lead {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 768px;
  }
  .about-background {
    background: white;
  }
  .about-background h2 {
    font-size: 0.6;
    margin-left: 8em;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron about-background">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2><strong>We are InCFO</strong></h2>
        <p class="lead" style="margin-top: 4em; padding-right: 7em;">Our mission to provide a range of financial services to companies to make their financial needs easy that needed to run and expand their business.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow bounce">
      <a class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-3x" href="#do" v-smooth-scroll></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to align them in center in one line.

Comment: do you want header in separate and paragraph separate?

Comment: Yes I want them seperate both should be displayed one after the another.

Comment: use this `@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .col-sm-6{
    min-width:100% !important;}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use min-width 100% for .col-sm-6

```
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { .col-sm-6{ min-width:100% !important;}}
```